# camera/render trick to distort an object and make it's sides visible from a top-down view

Tags: rendering, camera

To demonstrate what I want to achieve, I will use a cube:[image]

Basically I want to render the cube in such a way that make it's sides visible from a top-down view **without** modifying the object, just using some sort of camera/render trick.

As if I just scaled the bottom of the cube, just like the pic bellow. (ofc modifying the object is not something i want)

[image]

[image]

I took a look at the Panaromic type camera (using cycles render) and selecting "fish eye" panaroma type but I got no results that satisfied my condition. I'm unsure what I can try now.

thanks in advance

Comment: Blender's 3D world obeys Euclidean Geometry rules. What you are looking for is inverse perspective rendering like in spherical geometry. Check this video for more information : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY9GAyJtuJ0 You can fake it by applying a spherical inversion on the models themselves using Geometry nodes but you'll probably need more subdivisions in your model to look good. Please explain in more detail what what exactly you want to achieve and provide some additional details in your question.

Comment: For my specific usercase, I want to make 2d sprites for a game engine. 

I took a look at inverse/reverse perspective rendering that you talked about and I found a specific patch that seems to implement it on Blender: https://blenderartists.org/t/reverse-perspective-rendering/1213342/46

i'm having difficulties on how to apply said patch and for some reasson the build the user uploaded does not show the patch for me (can't see the option to enable/scale the reverse perspective)

Comment: i got one of his builds to work (3.50) and its exactly what I need. i can render objects the way that i imagined it

thanks for leading me into it!
now I just need to build blender myself with the patch for my preferable version

Comment: Hi Sneed. This is awesome. I didn't know such thing was implemented in Blender. Good luck! Hopefully, you will share your results with us soon. Non-Euclidian Geometry is quite fascinating, right ;)